# React Native - render a component onClick on an Icon

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, setstate

A part of my app has an 'icon'. When I 'click' on the icon, the State of the parent component changes to 'true' and I want a new 'Component' to render saying 'I am a new Component'. I am trying like this below, there is no error showing at the debugger. The Icon is an image component that I am importing. Here is the Code.

This is the parent Component

```
   import React, {Component} from 'react';
   import {View} from 'react-native';
   import {Icon} from '../ui/Icon';


   type HomeSceneState = {
    calendarState:boolean
  }


  class HomeScene extends Component<HomeSceneState> {
        state = {
           calendarState:false
          }

        openCalendar = () => {
           console.log("open calendar")
           this.setState({
           calendarState : true
          })

         }

       render() {
          return (
     
            <View style={{marginBottom: spacing.double,
                   backgroundColor:"black", flexDirection:"row"
                   }}>
              <View>
              <Icon onPress = {() => this.openCalendar()} />
              {this.calendarState ? <Casie/> : null }
             </View>

           </View>
    
          );
        }
       }

      export default HomeScene;
```

The Children Component looks like below

```
   class Casie extends Component<CalendarProps> {

      render() {
        return (
          <View>
           I am a new Component
        </View>
        );
      }
    }
  
    export default Casie;
```

Comment: you can use react navigation for navigating  the page

Comment: Can you put an example?

Answer (score 0):

replace  `<Calendar/>` by your  child component name `<Casie/>` (in your case). It seems you are not rendering your child component when the state changes.

Answer (score 0):

In your parent component you import the  react native navigation.
after you can use useNavigation for navigate the page. Sorry my english.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native'

class HomeScene extends Component<HomeSceneState> {
    state = {
       calendarState:false
      }

    openCalendar = () => {
       console.log("open calendar")
       navigation.navigate('Casie')
     }

   render() {
      return (...)
       
    }
   }

  export default HomeScene;
```